# How to get Jupiter in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, 13.04, power-management, jupiter

So I switched from ubuntu to gnomebuntu today, and proceeded to try and install all the apps that I had found invaluable with ubuntu. I have run into a road block with jupiter, and was wondering if anyone knew any tricks for installing it in 13.04. Or had a guide that was up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter is no longer being supported, so I think it will be getting harder to install it on newer distributions like 13.04 (which I assume you are using), besides not receiving any further fixes or updates. My advice is to stay away from it and try some alternatives like[TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html), that features similar power saving optimization.